# Can't login to django admin account after creating super user

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, superuser

I created a project in django and the first thing I want to do is to create a superuser for admin account and then proceed with the django project but the problem is after creating a superuser account using

python manage.py createsuperuser

and filling out the information the superuser gets created it says

Superuser created successfully.

But when I try to login with these credentials it says

Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

I am not sure if there is some other setting that I need to check out or I am doing something wrong.

Please suggest me solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run `python manage.py migrate` before you ran `python manage.py createsuperuser`?
During `createsuperuser` process, you need the username and password, you don't need anything else, i.e. email.

You should do this first, then run `python manage.py runserver`

lastly, navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`

There really isn't anything else you would need to do.  If you are getting another error, please post it.

Comment: Thanks, I was using email field where it was supposed to be the username. It works now.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the python shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

In the python console, run the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.get(username='your_username') # enter inside the quotes the username you entered when you ran python manage.py createsuperuser
user.set_password('new_password') # change the password 
user.is_superuser = True
user.is_staff = True
user.save()

exit()
```

Then try to login again using the credentials you set.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems too but by doing as follows it worked fine.

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    user = self.create_user(username, email, password=password, is_staff=True, **extra_fields)
    user.is_active = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return
```